# How to know if a tof VL53L0x sensor is dead or not

Tags: i2c

I bought a bunch of VL530X time-of-flight sensors on Aliexpress. They seemed to work fine. Then I connected two of them on the same Arduino Uno board to test with the Adafruit example "dual". During rewiring I may have used the 5v power pin of the Arduino instead of the 3.3v (I can't remember).

Now the sensors won't boot. They fail during setup with error -6 which is documented as "RANGE ERROR".

Yet, scanning for either of them does find a sensor at the default address 0x29.

How can one know if they're dead or if they can somehow be revived?

The Uno works fine with any other VL53L0x, just not those two. I could certainly just trash the ones that won't boot but I would be interested in a procedure to know for sure; it would be very useful when going into production.

The [last answer on this thread an ST forum](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D53W00000BIk0B/vl53l0x-stopped-working-suddenly-) points to the I2C bus, but I don't understand what is being recommended.

Comment: If others work and these don't, and the wiring and code is the same then yes, they are dead. What about them has died? Impossible to tell. It's basically one chip on a board. Maybe the laser diode has burned out. You could try inspecting it with your mobile phone camera which may be able to see the infra-red light - try it with a good one first and compare it. Not much else you can do beside that.

Comment: Thank you. What is confusing to me is that they respond to scanning. I was hoping there would exist some probing software that would be able to diagnose the problem further...